# Firestore getting multiple onSnapshot notifications

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I recently started getting multiple `onSnapshot` notifications when I change a document in a collection in Google Cloud Firestore.
The first one is the expected local change, with `doc.metadata.hasPendingWrites==true`, so I ignore that, but then right after that I get another change with `doc.metadata.hasPendingWrites==false`, as if the doc was changed by some other client remotely. But I'm the only one touching the database so I'm certain it's not that.

Since I think someone else has modified the doc, things get all screwed up in my app when this happens. The [Firestore docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.SnapshotMetadata) say you can get another notification if you've opted in to metadata-only changes, but I haven't. (I tried explicitly setting that to false -- no change.) I also checked for `.fromCache` but that's also false. So I'm confused!

To save the doc I'm just doing the usual:

```js
    await db().collection(collName))
      .doc(id)
      .set(shotData)
```

and the onSnapshot request looks like this:

```js
    if (shotsNotificationsUnsubscribe)
      shotsNotificationsUnsubscribe()

    shotsNotificationsUnsubscribe = db().collection(collnName).onSnapshot(ref => {
      ref.docChanges().forEach(change => {
        const {newIndex, oldIndex, doc, type} = change
        // Ignore modifications from local writes
        if (doc.metadata.hasPendingWrites) {
          console.log(`Ignoring local mod of shot ${doc.data().kind} "${type}"`)
          return
        }
        console.log(`Handling mod of shot ${doc.data().kind} "${type}"`)
```

This is in a typescript web client using firebase@7.5.2. What I get is:

```
Ignoring local mod of shot ShotData "modified"
Handling mod of shot ShatData "modified"
```

Comment: Is this typo in last line `ShatData/ShotData`? Why don't you try to analyze whole change to find the source of this log?

Comment: Sorry yes, my typo. I'm not sure what are you suggesting I analyze? I know which _line_ is printing the excess log, I'm just unclear as to _why_ it is sending me the excess notification.